# How do I evaluate two matrices with truth values?

Tags: matrices, logic

In one of my lectures I am given the following examples. I have included the a-c and 1-3 letters and numbers to make things a little easier:

[image]

What I'm struggling with is how to evaluate the initial matrices to get to stage 2. Do I evaluate R's A1 with S's A1 and then R's B1 with S's B1 but then I of course run out of elements. How exactly do I evaluate the two matrices in-terms of the positional coordinates provided to get to stage 2.

Comment: Do you mean how to perform matrix multiplications using logical values?

Comment: I think the question is how to perform matrix multiplication at all. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication

Comment: How did my lecturer get to stage 2 basically. I take it he combined true/false values from R and S to get there. Which values did he combine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lecturer used matrix multiplication. The answer by @Mauro ALLEGRANZA gives better detail.

[image]

Edit: Sorry for not using LaTex here.

Answer (score 2):

It is the [matrix product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Matrix_product_.28two_matrices.29) applied to the matrice $\mathbf{A}$ ($3 \times 3$) and $\mathbf{B}$ ($3 \times 2$) of truth-values.

The "generic" term $(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B})_{ij}$ of the result is computed according to the formula :

> $$(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B})_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^m A_{ik}B_{kj}$$

where instead of $+$ we have $\lor$ and instead of $\times$ we have $\land$.